# Pthreads, trying to use semaphores to print out sections of numbers from multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

The problem I'm having is this:  I have my "parent" going through a for loop, from 0 to 4.  On each iteration, I have 3 threads that I want to print out their "segment" of 12 numbers (0 to 11).

For example, when the parent loop is at 0,  thread 0 will print out 0, thread 1 will print out 4, thread 2 will print out 8.

When the parent loop is at 1, thread 0 will print out 1, thread 1 will print out 5, thread 2 will print out 9.

So ideally the output would be 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 .  I know that you can't determine when threads run, so it won't be exactly in that order, but I at least want to get 0 1 and 2 printed before the threads print 3 4 or 5.

That's what I'm having problems with.  It seems like one thread or another gets left in the dust and doesn't print out its segment, or doesn't fully print out its segment along with the other threads.  This is a problem I'm doing to try and fully understand semaphores.

I have two semaphores, one that blocks the parent (Producer?) when the threads are working, and one that blocks each thread until the producer increments to the next index.  I thought that in this way I could force them to wait for each other to get finished before continuing, but for some reason I'm having issues.

Here's my code:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define maxNum 12

sem_t parentSem;
sem_t threadSem;
int finishedThreads;
int done = 0;
int stuff[12];
int i;

void* threadFunction(int m){
    int printNum;
    int baseNum;
    //Determine the value the thread should start at
    baseNum = (double)(maxNum/3) * m;
    while(!done){ //ensure thread doesn't exit before parent is done with whole loop
        //wait for parent to increment
        sem_wait(&threadSem);
        printNum = baseNum + i;

            //keep track of how many threads are finished to let parent continue
        finishedThreads++;
        if(finishedThreads == 3){
                    //let parent continue if all threads are finished
            sem_post(&parentSem);
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv[]){

    sem_init(&parentSem, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&threadSem, 0, 0);
    int rc;
    pthread_t threads[3];
    int l; 
    for(l = 0; l < 12; l++){
        stuff[l] = l;
    }
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadFunction, (void*) j);

    }
    int k;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        sem_wait(&parentSem); //wait for children here (initially sem set to 1)
        finishedThreads = 0; //set finished thread counter to 0
        for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            //increment thread semaphore to 3 so each thread can run
            sem_post(&threadSem);
        }
    }
    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }



}
```

How can I ensure that all threads run prior to the parent incrementing?  How can I make sure that all threads run per "round" without any being stuck behind? Sometimes the same thread runs twice instead of each thread running once..... help?

Thank you all very much for your help.

EDIT: New code state: (Thread function)

```
while(!done){

    printf("Thread %d not done yet...\n", m);
    if(m == 0){
        sem_wait(&threadSem0);
    }else if(m == 1){
        sem_wait(&threadSem1);
    }else if(m == 2){
        sem_wait(&threadSem2);
    }
    printNum = baseNum + i;
    printf("Thread %d past waiting, number segment: %d\n", m, printNum);

    finishedThreads++;
    if(finishedThreads == 3){
        sem_post(&parentSem);
    }
}
```

Parent portion:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("In parent for loop, counter: %d\n", i);
    printf("Parent past wait semaphore\n");
    finishedThreads = 0;
    if(i == 3) done = 1;
    sem_post(&threadSem0);
    sem_post(&threadSem1);
    sem_post(&threadSem2);
    sem_wait(&parentSem);
}
for(i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: You should probably use condition variables, and you *must* have a critical section around accesses to `finishedThreads`. Without the critical section, the code is defective (and will sometimes lose counts).

Comment: I looked into condition variables. I couldn't figure out how to use them properly.  Are you saying that I should put a mutex around where I increment finishedThreads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make access to `finishedThreads` atomic to avoid each thread to only use a cached copy. Does your programme work when compiled without optimization(*)?

The proper way to do this in C++ is to use `std::atomic`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329234/stdthread-c-more-threads-same-data)'s thorough answer.

### Update:

Using one single semaphore for all the child threads can create problems if the threads are looping quickly, as in your case. You have to use one semaphore per child thread to overcome this issue.

```
sem_t threadSem[3];

// ...

sem_wait(&threadSem+m);

// ...

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    sem_init(threadSem+i, 0, 0);

// ...

    for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
        //increment each thread semaphore so each thread can run
        sem_post(threadSem+k);
    }
```

Another few things that I didn't catch early on:

You use the variable `i` to do the increment in `threadFunction`. This cannot work. The  correct formula should be only depending on `m`. Since each thread has its own copy of `baseNum` and `printNum`, you can use them without problem:

```
baseNum = (double)(maxNum/3) * m;
while(!done){ //ensure thread doesn't exit before parent is done with whole loop
    //wait for parent to increment
    sem_wait(&threadSem);
    printNum++;
    // ....
```

You have a lot of things in your code which depend on the number of child threads, I suggest using a constant for that (like you did for `maxNum`).

You don't set the variable `done` to indicate the end of work for the child threads.

```
volatile int done;

// in threadFunction

 // wait for start
sem_wait(threadSem+m)
while(!done){ 
    // thread work here
    // ...
    //wait for parent to increment at the end of the loop
    sem_wait(threadSem+m);
}

// in main

for(k = 0; k < 3; k++){
    //increment each thread semaphore so each thread can run
    if (i == 4) done = 1;
    sem_post(threadSem+k);
}
```

Of course `done` must also follow the "`volatile` or mutexed" rule.

You don't join all the threads at the end:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

---

(*) if you are using gcc, I mean with the parameter `-O0` and even debug with `-g`.

Comment: Uhh I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Without optimization".  If you mean "without semaphores" then it doesn't really work because the FOR loop simply counts through it, and the threads finish up without waiting, printing out only one number.

Comment: With that code above, I'm currently getting something like this:
Parent FOR is 0 --
Thread 1: 4
Thread 2: 8
Thread 0: Didn't run
Parent FOR is 1 --
Thread 0: 1
Thread 1: 5
Thread 2: 9
Parent FOR is 2 --
Thread 0: 2
Thread 2: 10
Thread 1: 6
Parent FOR is 3 --
Thread 0: 3
Thread 1: Didn't run
Thread 2: Didn't run

Segmentation fault

Comment: I really don't know what -O0 does, but it does compile and gives the right output (Still with seg fault) when I have finishedThreads as volatile.  It does even if I don't use -O0 as a parameter.  However, every once in a while there will be the same thread running multiple times in one "round".  It's better than it was, but still not working quite correctly.

Comment: Now, with it specified as Volatile, the output looks like this:

4 8 0 5 9 1 6 10 2 7 11 3

which is correct.  But then upon running it again a time or two, it will give this:

8 8 0 9 9 5 10 6 2 11 7 3

which is one thread running multiple times.

Comment: One second, trying to implement your suggestions

Comment: included the necessary modifications for the semaphores.

Comment: Alright. Creating one semaphore for each thread works just fine.  I still get a seg fault at the end, do you happen to have any guesses as to why that is?  Also, is there a way to create an array of N semaphores?  The program I'm trying to test this code for actually doesn't have a pre-specified number of threads.

Comment: one more effort, we're almost there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25925/discussion-between-feralshadow-and-didierc)

Answer (score 0):

You're in need of a barrier, specifically a reusable one. It might be useful to take a look at Allen Downey's Little Book of Semaphores, section 3.6.7, reproduced [here](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~kishore/papers/semaphores.pdf) (PDF). The code is in Python, but the gist of it is clear enough. It requires one mutex and two counting semaphores, and in your case you've 4 participants in the barrier.

You could control which thread gets woken up first by setting thread priorities so that the first thread is the most important, and so on.