# std::thread c++. More threads same data

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, heap-memory, std

Im using visual studio 2012 and c++11. I dont understand why this does not work:

```
void client_loop(bool &run)
{
    while ( run );
}

int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    std::thread t(&client_loop,std::ref(running));

    running = false ;
    t.join();
}
```

In this case, the loop of thread `t` never finishes but I explicity set `running` to `false`. `run` and `running` have the same location. I tried to set `running` as a single global variable but nothing happens. I tried to pass a pointer value too but nothing.

The threads use the same heap. I really don't understand. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your program terminates too early to ever observe anything interesting.

Comment: nope, i forgot to write in this example  "t.join()" .. :)

Comment: what if you set `running` as `volatile`?

Comment: @didierc: If he sets it as `volatile`, he'll probably be deceived into thinking he has working code. Microsoft defines `volatile` so it'll work, but the standard doesn't require it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thx, I guess I got this wrong at some point sometime ago. I stand corrected.

Comment: Remember that the compiler is allowed to do practically _any_ kind of modifications to the code, as long as the observable single-threading behaviour is not changed. This includes reordering of code, using a CPU register instead of the memory variable (e.g. a loop counter is incremented in a register and may get updated in memory only after the loop is finished), etc. With standard variable types, there are no guarantees whatsoever for multi-threading, just because they are very expensive in terms of computation time. If you need guarantees, you have to specify them, e.g. by using atomics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your program has **Undefined Behavior**, because it introduces a data race on the `running` variable (one thread writes it, another thread reads it).

You should use a mutex to synchronize access, or make `running` an `atomic<bool>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

void client_loop(std::atomic<bool> const& run)
{
    while (run.load());
}

int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> running(true);
    std::thread t(&client_loop,std::ref(running));

    running = false ;
    t.join();

    std::cout << "Arrived";
}
```

See a working [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%242280).

Comment: thank you, I (stupidly) thought that no precaution was needed if the second thread only read data.. I didnt know the "atomic" variable: But now that I uncovered im very happy. thanks again

Comment: @MatteoGaleotti It may have even worked on reasonable architectures (though still being UB,of course), hadn't this infinite loop been that simple to be merely optimized out.

Comment: Two notes. First, `run` probably should not be declared `const`. Granted, the compiler can't optimize out the load, but still, the function assumes that the value changes. Second, the `.load()` isn't needed; `while (run) ;` also works; `run` is contextually converted to `bool`, which ends up applying its `operator bool()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Regarding `load()`, you're right, thank you for pointing that out. Regarding `const`, I've put it there to specify that `client_loop()` itself is not going to modify the value. Does putting `const` also imply that the function doesn't expect the value to change? I would say the answer is "no", but your comment seems to imply it is "yes". If so, could you please expand a bit?

Answer (score 0):

The `const` probably doesn't affect the compiler's view of the code. In a single-threaded application, the value won't change (and this particular program is meaningless). In a multi-threaded application, since it's an atomic type, the compiler can't optimize out the load, so in fact there's no real issue here. It's really more a matter of style; since `main` modifies the value, and `client_loop` looks for that modification, it doesn't seem right to me to say that the value is `const`.